# Why do I get this error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LocationsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I keep getting this error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LocationsController#index

Couldn't find Location without an ID

@location= Location.find(params[:id])
```

Im using gmaps4rails and displaying information in the infowindow partial.  I can display the location address just fine, but when I start attempting to display chef info I get the above errors.

Location Model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_gmappable
belongs_to :chef
validates :chef_id, :zipcode, :address, presence: true

def gmaps4rails_address
  "#{address}, #{zipcode}"
end


end
```

Chef Model:

```
class Chef < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :meals, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :location
end
```

Locations controller:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController

    def index

    @location= Location.find(params[:id])
    @chef = Chef.find(@location.chef_id)


    @locations = Location.all

    @json = @locations.to_gmaps4rails do |location, marker|
marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/locations/infowindow", :locals => { :location => location})
marker.title "#{location.address}"
marker.json({ :zipcode => location.zipcode})

  end


end


def self.save_all
Location.all.each { |location| location.save! }
end

end
```

infowindow partial

```
<%= location.address %>
<% @chef.each do |chef| %>
    <%= chef.name %>
<% end %>
```

Anyone help... Please before I blow my computer up...

Comment: Where exactly do you provide :id in your index route???

Comment: I am including all resources in routes.  Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: I'm implying that /locations is restful route to LocationsController#index action. There is no :id parameter there... Unless you provide it like /locations?id=.. or change your route.. So the error is very rightfully there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error

`Couldn't find Location without an ID`

on

`@location= Location.find(params[:id])`

line in your `index` action because you didn't pass any `:id` in your `params` so `params[:id] is nil`

**UPDATE**

Assuming that you have nested routes defined in `routes.rb` i.e., `locations` nested within `chefs` routes then, you should directly receive the `chef_id` in params. 
Then, your `index` action should look like

```
def index    
    @chef = Chef.find(params[:chef_id])       
    @locations = Location.all   
    @json = @locations.to_gmaps4rails do |location, marker|
marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/locations/infowindow", :locals => { :location => location})
marker.title "#{location.address}"
marker.json({ :zipcode => location.zipcode})    
  end
```

**UPDATE 2**

As per the chat session with OP, OP didn't have any nested routes. All OP wanted was to display `chef.name` for a particular location.

In the `index` view,

```
<%= @locations.each do |location| %>
   <%= location.chef.try(:name) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So I changed it to @location= Location.find(params[:chef_id]) and am getting this undefined method `each' on this line <% @chef.each do |chef| %> any ideas?

Comment: right, but chef_id is not in the chef model.  Chef_Id is linked from location model to chef model on chefs Id

Comment: Yes..BUT `chef_id` is an existing `id` of a `Chef` record. So you can just query Chef table directly to fetch the `Chef` record.

Comment: Nope, still getting this **Couldn't find Chef without an ID** on this line **@chef = Chef.find(params[:chef_id]) ** I cant figure this out lol.

Comment: chef return single record not chefs collection. You cant use each on chef instance variable

Comment: @Georgi Thanks for joining the chat and helping.